# why cant we use raw_input in functions?

Tags: python

the error for the following code is in question:- (i want to make it so we can input the value and that value may be taken as a variable)

```
def hotel_cost(nights):
  return 140 * nights

def plane_ride_cost(city):
  if city == "Charlotte":
    return 183
  elif city == "Tampa":
    return 220
  elif city == "Pittsburgh":
    return 222
  elif city == "Los Angeles":
    return 475

def rental_car_cost(days):
  cost = days * 40
  if days >= 7:
    cost -= 50
  elif days >= 3:
    cost -= 20
  return cost

def trip_cost(city, days, spending_money):
  return rental_car_cost(days) + hotel_cost(days) + plane_ride_cost(city) + spending_money


city = raw_input("Which city will you stay in ")
days = raw_input("How long is the stay ")
spending_money = raw_input("How much is your spening budget ")


print trip_cost(city, days, spending_money)
```

Error showing it's:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "python", line 31, in <module>
  File "python", line 23, in trip_cost
  File "python", line 17, in rental_car_cost
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -=: 'str' and 'int'
```

Comment: I don't see the error written in the question. You have several issues though, such as indentation and a `return` statement going over multiple lines.

Comment: Nowhere in this code are you using `raw_input` in a function.

Comment: `raw_input` returns a `str`. But in `trip_cost` you add it to `int`s. You may want to convert it first using `int()`. And, as others mentioned indirectly, your indentation is off.

Comment: You can use `raw_input` in functions. And you can use the strings returned by `raw_input` in functions. But if you want to do arithmetic with that input data you need to convert it into numbers, using `int()` or `float()`.

Comment: guys i'm kinda new to coding so excuse my many mistakes... in my initial code my indentation was fine but writing it here I might hav made some mistakes xP... otherwise thanks for the help :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use `int` and `float` here

```
city = raw_input("Which city will you stay in ")
days = int(raw_input("How long is the stay "))
spending_money = float(raw_input("How much is your spening budget "))
```